# Firefox's shader editor can not get youtube 360 video shader

Tags: glsl, webgl, shader

[The WebGL inspector](https://benvanik.github.io/WebGL-Inspector/) (a tool for inspecting WebGL commands) and The [Firefox shader editor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Shader_Editor) can inspect the 360 video shader in Facebook's 360 video player for when I try to inspect the Youtube page to look at it's shader the inspector is not able to inspect it even though I can verify youtube is using WebGL.

[image]

Why are neither of these tools able to inspect youtube's WebGL 360 video player? Or, rather how I can inspect the 360 video shaders on youtube?

Comment: I don't know why this question was closed. It seems super clear to anyone familiar with WebGL development. The answer though is simple, those inspectors use various means to try to um *inspect* WebGL and whatever means they were using was not sufficient for all cases. I tried the Canvas debugger in Firefox developer edition but no luck there. I found the [Shader Editor extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shader-editor/ggeaidddejpbakgafapihjbgdlbbbpob?hl=en) managed to be able to inspect the shader where as several other extensions did not.

Comment: will give a more detailed answer if this question is re-opened